# How to check date interval is in another interval

Tags: r

I have created cols and rows with following code

```
    library(lubridate)    

date1<-ymd_hms("2000-01-01 05:30:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  
date2<- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")

cols <- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  mapply(function(y,z){
    interval((date1+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date1+days(x)+minutes(y+z)))
  }, y = c(0,150,420,600,720,840,1080), z = c(600,570,600,600,600,600,600), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
})

rows <- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  mapply(function(y,z){
    interval((date2+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date2+days(x)+minutes(y+z)))
  }, y = seq(0,1380,60), rep(c(60),24), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
})
```

The requirement is to create a matrix with cols and rows and with 1's and 0's. 1's if row interval is in column interval else with 0's

Answer (score 0):

Intervals are composed of `start`: date of start, `.Data`: seconds of duration of the interval and `tzone`: time zone.

Asumming that you `tzone` is stable, you only need to reconstruct the start date of the two intervals you want to compare and check that one starts after the second and ends before the second.

Example:

```
    isIncluded <- function(a,b){
      (a[[1]]@start>=b[[1]]@start & (a[[1]]@start+seconds(a[[1]]@.Data))<=(b[[1]]@start+seconds(b[[1]]@.Data)))
    }

 library(lubridate)    

date1<-ymd_hms("2000-01-01 05:30:00",tz = "US/Eastern")  
date2<- ymd_hms("2000-01-01 00:00:00",tz = "US/Eastern")

cols <- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  mapply(function(y,z){
    interval((date1+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date1+days(x)+minutes(y+z)))
  }, y = c(0,150,420,600,720,840,1080), z = c(600,570,600,600,600,600,600), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
})

rows <- lapply(0:14, function(x){
  mapply(function(y,z){
    interval((date2+days(x)+minutes(y)), (date2+days(x)+minutes(y+z)))
  }, y = seq(0,1380,60), rep(c(60),24), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
})  
    x <- cols[[1]][1]
    y <- cols[[1]][2]
    isIncluded(x,y) ## Is included x in y? False
    isIncluded(x,x) ## Is included x in x? True

The rest is just populating the matrix!
Best!
```

Comment: please add to my code . i am not able to relate a,b,start,,.Data

Comment: Hi! It is just a function. You "send" it two intervals and it give you back `TRUE` if the first one is in the second one and `FALSE` otherwise. The rest is your code. You only need to loop `cols` and `rows` to populate your matrix! `Start`, `.Data` are just the elements that compose each one of your intervals!